# nginx failed to open websocket connection due to invalid connection header: keep alive

Tags: python, nginx, websocket

i have a python websocket server and i want to served it in nginx. so this is my server code :

```
import asyncio 
import websockets


async def recv_message(websocket, path):

    message = await websocket.recv()
    print(message)


def main():

    start_server = websockets.serve(recv_message, "localhost", 8765)

    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

and this is my nginx config:

```
server{
     listen 8765;
     server_name localhost;

     location / {
     proxy_pass ws://localhost;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";

 }

}
```

when i go to `localhost:8765`, i get a message from the webpage, it says

```
Failed to open a WebSocket connection: invalid Connection header: keep-alive.

You cannot access a WebSocket server directly with a browser. You need a WebSocket client.
```

how do i open the websocket connection? is there any mistake in my configuration? i'm keep stucking in this problem since i'm new in software engineering. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, you have to open up the address with a 'front-end'.
You should be able to connect using these two files:

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="client.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

**client.js:**

```
function startSocket() {
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8765/")
    ws.onopen = function(event) {
        ws.send("Sent this from client.js")
    }
}
startSocket();
```